# Oxidizing and Reducing agent in redox reaction

Tags: redox, oxidation-state

> In the oxidation-reduction reaction
>
> $\ce{Sn^{4+} + 2 Fe^{2+} -> 2 Fe^{3+} + Sn^{2+}}$
>
> (A) $\ce{Sn^{4+}}$ is the oxidizing agent and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is the
>   reducing agent.
>
> (B) $\ce{Sn^{4+}}$ is the reducing agent and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is the
>   oxidizing agent.
>
> (C) $\ce{Sn^{4+}}$ is the reducing agent and $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ is the
>   oxidizing agent.
>
> (D) $\ce{Fe^{3+}}$ is the oxidizing agent and $\ce{Sn^{2+}}$ is the
>   reducing agent.

**My thoughts:** Because $\ce{Sn^{4+}}$ is getting reduced, and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is getting oxidized, then $\ce{Sn^{4+}}$ is therefore an oxidizing agent, and $\ce{Fe^{2+}}$ is a reducing agent, which leads me to believe that A is the right answer. However, the answer key says D. I note that (D) is true for the reverse reaction, but why would A not be true then?

Comment: Yea, D lists the products not the reactants. Sometimes the answer key is wrong and A is right ;)

Comment: If I were you @DisplayName, I'd avoid using that book.